# After formulating the recurrence for a dynamic programming algorithm, how can we fill in the table?

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic

A recurrence relationship is an imperative part of a dynamic programming approach.

I was solving the problem of finding the minimum number of edits needed to create a palindromic string.

```
dp[i, j] = min(
               dp[i+1, j-1] if s[i] == s[j],
               dp[i+1, j-1] +1,
               dp[i+1, j] +1
               dp[i, j-1] +1
)
```

After formulating the recursive equation, it's trivial to implement a top down approach that uses a hash table.

What I can't understand is how to use this recursive formula to build the solution table from the bottom up. By doing it bottom up, we save memory as we don't need to compute a recursion stack. It's also a bit more elegant to do it bottom up.

So, to flip this recurrence and start from the bottom up. We need to consider substrings that have a length of 1 to length of N. However, I'm struggling with creating these for loops appropriately.

My question: **Once formulating the top-down recurrence for a DP problem, how do we flip it and use a bottom up approach to fill in the subsolution table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fill it starting from 'smallest' problems to 'largest'.

> We need to consider substrings that have a length of 1 to length of N

Yes, that's right. Let's iterate through the lengths in the outer loop:

```
for len in range(1, n+1):
     for i in range(n-len+1):
         dp[i][i+len-1] = ...
```

Comment: Cool. Though I don't quite understand the second loop. `for i in range(n-len+1):` That is, I don't understand why this is here.

Comment: Also - should it be `for i in range(n-len):` why did you add the plus one?

Comment: @彼得名姓, `i` is a start of the interval of length `len`, the end of this interval is `i+len-1`. But we also need to prevent going out of the array bounds, thus we need to limit `i` with `n-len`.

Comment: @彼得名姓, we need to go through all values from `0` to `n-len` inclusively. That's why `range(n-len+1)`, we are talking about python's `range()`, right?

Comment: I suppose a related question: how do we track the solution during this numerical optimization process? That is, suppose I wanted to find what this solution was. I suppose I should make this a separate question.

Comment: @彼得名姓, usually you need to create another array to store what exact choice you've done when calculating the best value. And at the end, you need to go backwards to build the result.

Comment: Thanks! So, in addition to dp, we need another `solution` matrix that keeps track of the solution for any given i or j?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163600/discussion-between-dale-and-).

Answer (score 2):

In your recursive formula, the value for each cell `dp[i,j]` is calculated the values with *larger* `i` and/or *smaller* `j`.

If you want to calculate the cells bottom-up, you just have to visit them in an appropriate order, so that the cells you need for every `dp[i,j]` are already done by the time you get there.

Since you need all the larger `i`s to be done, visit cells in order of *decreasing* first coordinate, and since you need all the smaller `j`s to be done, visit cells in order of *increasing* second coordinate.  It doesn't really matter which coordinate is in the inner or outer loop.